# Prove Uniform Convergence of Series of functions-Help?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Let F0 be a bounded Riemann integrable function on [0, 1]. For n ∈ N,  define $F_n(x)$ on [0,1] by
$F_n(x)$ = $\int_{0}^{x}$ $F_{n-1}(t)$ dt

1) Prove that for all  n∈ N and x∈ [0,1],  we have |$F_n(x)$| < M $\frac {x^n} {n!}$   where M is a strictly positive constant.

2) Deduce that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty$ $F_k (x)$ converges uniformly on [0,1]

I have worked it and got $F_{n-1}(x)$ < M$e^x$  = M$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$  $\frac {x^n} {n!}$ which implies $F_n(x)$ < M$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$  $\frac {x^{n+1}} {n\,!}$

which implies

|$F_n(x)$| < M$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$  $\frac {x^n} {n!}$

But the problem is I need to show :
 |$F_n(x)$| < M $\frac {x^n} {n!}$

Please help someone

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use induction, where the base case $F_1$ is proved by using a global bound $M$ on $|F_0|$.

Comment: I got it to work..thanks!